# Сan bitwise ssh client keep several consoles to different environments?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, sftp

I use bitwise ssh client(www.bitvise.com) beacause it allow use sftp and ssh together. But sometimes I need keep 2(or more) connections to several servers

It is not comfortable to login and unlogin each time.

Does ssh client allows this?

If no - please share analogs or just ideas.

thanks

Comment: Open several terminals, each with its own ssh connection. Alternatively, use a terminal multiplexer, like *screen* or *byobu*, which allow you to detach from a terminal (while still keeping the program running in it going), then re-attach at a later time, at your convenience.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I need in more detailed explanation

Comment: Why dont'you try Googling *byobu* and/or *screen*? Their home pages provide plenty of explanation.